# selection input label disappears after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a multiple selection dropdown of options that when selected the value renders above in a label. When you click the label you can append a new text value to the initial value. It's for a meal plan app, so you chose a food item and add a serving size for a better understanding. Problem is the render label of the last item always disappears. The values in state are updating correctly, it is just the last label.

```
const renderLabel = (label, i) => ({
    content: result.monday.breakfast.fruits[i],
    onClick: () => {
      const servingSize = prompt(label.key = ' serving size:');
      if (servingSize !== null) {
        const newArr = update(result,
          {monday: {breakfast: {fruits: {$apply: (arr) => {
            arr[i] = arr[i] + ' ' + servingSize;
            return arr;
          }}}}}  
        );
        if (newArr) {
          setResult(newArr);
        };
      };
    }
  });
```

I'm using the 'semantic-ui-react' library for the  component and 'immutability-helper' for updating my nested objects.  I know it has something to do with not updating the content key that the renderLabel prop object is taking in in the  Component. This is my first real React project and I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. Any help or leads on how I should set things up are appreciated, thanks! Btw: the label prop takes in the option object so ex: {key: 'apple', text: 'apple', value: 'apple'}